# How do I remove the colon from DriveLetter

Tags: powershell

How can I remove the the colon from the DriveLetter that is manually entered?

```
$OutDrive = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please select a drive letter to create output        folders (e.g. c:)'
$DriveLetter = $OutDrive minus ":" ->trying to figure out what to put here
```

Comment: Are you trying to have them pick from available local drives?  Having them input it as text can be done, but there are other ways offer pickers from PowerShell that might be a better experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As PsDrives may have more than one letter, Martins solution might be better than  the simple

```
$DriveLetter = $OutDrive.Substring(0,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-replace` operator which is using *regex*. Note that the dollar sign ensures that you only remove a single trailing colon:

```
$DriveLetter = $OutDrive -replace ':$'
```

You could also do this using the string `trim()` method:

```
$DriveLetter = $OutDrive.Trim(':')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this easy :

```
$OutDrive = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please select a drive letter to create output        folders (e.g. c:)'
$DriveLetter = $OutDrive .Substring(0 , $OutDrive .IndexOf(":"))
```

Comment: This approach is not user-friendly as it throws an error if the user did not include a colon. @Martin's regular expression approach is cleaner.